# Does @interface with properties only require @implementation?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-2.0

I would like to define a C struct-like in my Objective-C header file which includes `_ivars` only, however, since this a header file only there would be no corresponding `@implementation`. Is that even possible? 
(I also don't want to force the header file includers to add `@implementation` since this is a simple descriptor definition)

I would like it to be `@interface` definition so users who like to extend it and add more data members to it could do so (again, only `_ivars`). However, other suggestions might work if you think of something.

Comment: Do you want to define a struct or a class?

Comment: @Willeke I would like it to be a class so others can extend it with categories if they want.

Comment: [Can I 'extend' a struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370533/can-i-extend-a-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there has to be an `@implementation` declared for the class that is compiled by the compiler to cause the class to be realized at runtime (including the storage backing the `@property` declarations.

Once compiled, that class cannot extended with additional `@properties` that are automatically backed (it can be extended via categories, but you're on your own for storage and categorical extensions of classes is generally not recommended anyway).

Comment: Thanks, I was hopping that I was missing something and that I would still be able to do it without "implementation" in case it is purely a C-struct style but wrapped up in an "interface". (by the way, I don't mind extending with categories)

Comment: You can add properties in a subclass.

Comment: @Willeke The problem with using a class (aka interface) is that I will need to add an implementation for it, and I am trying to avoid that since I am planning to have a header file only.

Comment: A class isn't an interface. Is a category header only?

Comment: I am writing a header only; I am not writing a .m file. I would like this structure I am proposing to be used when including the header the header w/o a corresponding .m implementation in case no extensions are required. If the "includers" want to extend it, then yeh, they would need to add a category into there .m file.

Comment: Even a structure has to be allocated somewhere.   By using a class (with @implementation), the instantiation of the class takes care of creating the backing store for your "structure" members.